# datePickerDialog spinner instead od calendar java programatically api 24

Tags: android

I want to display datePicker as dialog after user click a button. I followed this tutorial : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html and it works fina but I get displayed calendar instead of spinner. I tried a lot of things e.g. 
1) set theme the has mode spinner, 
2) There was an api :

```
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false)
    dialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnerShown(true)
```

but those method are deprecated and has no effect.

The only thing that worked is that I decompiled DatePicker and there was a code :

```
   private static final int MODE_SPINNER = 1;
   private static final int MODE_CALENDAR = 2;

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DatePicker,
            defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    final int mode = a.getInt(R.styleable.DatePicker_datePickerMode, MODE_SPINNER);
    final int firstDayOfWeek = a.getInt(R.styleable.DatePicker_firstDayOfWeek, 0);
    a.recycle();

    switch (mode) {
        case MODE_CALENDAR:
            mDelegate = createCalendarUIDelegate(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
            break;
        case MODE_SPINNER:
        default:
            mDelegate = createSpinnerUIDelegate(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
            break;
    }
```

if I changed "mode" in debug mode to value = "1" spinner appeared. But how can I set this value ? How to set style R.styleable.DatePicker_datePickerMode to 1 ?

Additionally R is some kind internal - don't know what it is:

```
    import com.android.internal.R;
```

Comment: Try to add <integer name="date_picker_mode">1</integer> to your values file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this API it is an error. 
I found a workaround https://gist.github.com/jeffdgr8/6bc5f990bf0c13a7334ce385d482af9f

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Theme to set a spinner like date picker. like below.

```
DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                }
            }, YEAR, MONTH, DAY);

mDatePickerDialog.show();
```

Note : See the DatePickerDialog constructor argument `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light` this will make your dialog as a spinner.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it is't working Only colors on the calendar ware changed